# adjustResize doesn't work with NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I add a NavigationView into my first fragment. Then I add(not replace) another fragment into the same container. Inside the second fragment there is an EditText. And adjustResize doesn't work with the EditText. Are there any solutions?